# How to solve keyerror in selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

I am very new to selenium webdriver so not able to understand about key error when i run this code snippet to launch Firefox using python. 
My code is  Self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
When run it's giving- Keyerror = 'message ' help me i am stuck here for 4 days ☹️

I am using
Python 3,
Selenium 3.3,
Firefox 52,
Geckodriver 0.15,

Comment: Can you give us the detailed description of the error?

Comment: sure this whole thing--

    
    
    start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 110, in check_response
    message = message['message']
KeyError: 'message'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read these link to improve your question and to have better chances to get some help: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have done a little bit of digging around this. Most notably there is a bug reported with the Selenium team regarding this issue (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3808). I am experiencing this same issue when I try to run remote.